# Aggregate on a non group by column check if any value matches a criteria

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Let's  say I have a table Category with columns
id,  childCategory, hasParts

Let's say I want to group by id and check if any value in hasParts has value true.

How to do this efficiently?

Comment: Unless I understood faulty to your question, you can use 'group by' and 'having' functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has got to be the most vague post that i've seen on here but i'll take a stab at it. based on my own imagination and the 3 sentences provided, here we go:

```
create table category (id int, childcategory nvarchar(25), hasparts bit)

insert category
select 1, 'stroller', 1
union all
select 1, 'rocker', 1
union all
select 2, 'car', 0
union all
select 2, 'doll', 0
union all
select 3, 'nasal sprayer', 0
union all
select 3, 'thermometer', 1

select *,
case when exists (select 1 from category b where a.id = b.id and b.hasparts = 1) then 'has true value' end as truecheck
from
(
select id, count(*) as inventory
from category
group by id
) a

drop table category
```

this should theoretically get you want you want. adjust as needed.